# The database is empty. issue

Tags: email, outlook, lotus

My client firm is using lotus notes client application and that is sending email to users and the users are using microsoft outlook 2010.

Email which is sending by lotus application when it comes to outllok it's coming as an attachment .nsf file.

We understand that user has to save the nsf to local drive first and open to respond works, but user are not trained to do so.  We need to solve this technical issue without having user save the nsf to local drive/desktop. When user clicks open on attached nsf file they are getting The database is empty message.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the sending method on Notes side. It should send text, RTF or HTML, not the DB attached.

Comment: Thanks Sultan for your response. I am not sending DB attached and I am just using RTF and text.

Comment: show me the code that you use to send a mail from lotus. you can pastebin it